# Unity3D: stack of thin boxes toppling despite perfect alignment

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, rigid-bodies, collider

Here is what happens when I copy&paste a few thin boxes, and then [vertex-snap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9X6y8WLo0Y) them to the ground and each other:

[image]

Pressing "Play" leads to the stack toppling.

I tried reducing the BoxCollider `y` to 0.99 and 0.95. No luck still.

Does anyone have recommendations to easily get a stacked wall to just stay up (until a **real** force is applied)? Maybe there is some sort of "glue" component to prevent two faces separating until a force exceeds some threshold?

Comment: This is exactly what would happen in the real world.

Comment: @JoeBlow Not in case of 0 wind and perfectly cut and placed objects. But I do get your point: In the real world, things are always imperfect and the physics engine reflects some of that imperfection perfectly :P

Comment: You've set the scale for us with the human.  We can imagine the weight of the objects, depending on what they are made of.   I can absolutely, 100%, totally, and completely, assure you that this is what would happen ***in the real world***, including indoors with "perfectly" (what does that mean?) cut engineering.

Comment: Anyway I'm providing the answer for you.

Comment: (BTW don't change the collider to ".99" or the like; that is totally irrelevant and won't help.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Actually, the 2D physics engine does require a buffer zone between colliders, so it was worth a try! Also, PLEASE do not edit other people's posts or topics carelessly - I'll give you a chance to remove the typo ("think boxes"), and rephrase it so that my topic (written by you) is not your opinion as being held by me (i.e. please rephrase it without any first person pronouns). If you are not willing to do that, please undo the edit.

Comment: Hi Domi.  Definitely re-edit if you like - don't hesitate.  (Anyone can edit anything any time on SO.)

Comment: (changing the size of colliders does NOT do what you think.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Not sure what PhysX suddenly does in that topic... I don't even have an NVIDIA card. I'll just undo your changes then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting their positions *manually* so that they are right under each other.

You shouldn't expect to be able to make a stack of 20-30 box colliders stacked on their smaller faces because of physics simulation inaccuracies, floating point errors and so on. If that's your intention and/or the above doesn't work, try using [Fixed Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) with a manually set Break Force and/or Break Torque.

You can also try increasing the [Solver Iteration Count](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-solverIterationCount.html) to something like 10 or 15 (which should do the trick in most cases), but it won't be good for performance in scenes with 1000s of objects.

Increasing the [Sleep Threshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-sleepThreshold.html) will also help in this specific case, but can cause problems like small objects sleeping when they have small (but not infinitesimal) velocities.

EDIT:
 A similar thing happens with my own custom physics engine. Another workaround you can do is to align the bodies and set them to sleep in `Start`. That way they'll stay upright (not moving rather) and topple when something collides with them.

Comment: "physics simulation inaccuracies" au contraire, mon frere! .. it's because it's working ***properly***. it's not a floating point error.  In real life, if you have two ***platonic*** steel cubes of 1 inch size.  ***And they are 1 inch apart***.  What that means is they are ***pressing in to each other very hard, and will spring apart***.  If they are "resting" on each other, they are (say) 1.00001 inch apart - not 1.00000 inch.

Comment: Quite simply, in PhysX, say ***you actually want*** two cubes to spring apart slightly.  What you do is, precisely, set them apart by their size!  Then PhysX will correctly spring them apart, ie exactly as if they just collided in motion.  OP is simply doing what you do ***if you want*** to make two objects "spring apart".

Comment: I have placed them *manually*, but with zero buffer zone (vertex-snapped, as I already explained)

Comment: @Domi manually as in set the values of the position manually.

Comment: @EvilTak I am using [vertex snapping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9X6y8WLo0Y). Same accuracy, much faster (unless there is a keyboard shortcut to directly focus the position input fields).

Comment: Hi Domi, I guess I am not speaking clearly, having repeated myself four or five times.  ***IF YOU VERTEX SNAP, IT WILL MAKE THEM "EXACTLY" EQUAL***.  Makes sense?   ***IN PHYSX, "EXACTLY EQUAL" SPECIFICALLY AND LITERALLY MEANS 'YOU WANT THEM TO SPRING APART***.  Am I getting any clearer?

Comment: Say you posted a question asking "So, I want to position two colliders so that, PhysX makes the 'bounce apart' once I release them. How do I do this?"  The answer is: "position them exactly touching, so if they are one meter cubes make them exactly one meter apart. on the next frame they will 'pop apart'"

Comment: you seem to have some confusion about the 'vertex snapping' feature in Unity, which is an interesting and fascinating feature but has ***utterly no connection*** to PhysX.  if you kinematically position two colliders "into" each other (ie "exactly no" gap between) that is *the same as bouncing them* in an ongoing bounce.  note that (as is common) when you deliberately want something to "appear and bounce away" you do, precisely, exactly what you have done!!!

Comment: @JoeBlow that's not what's happening here. Even if you leave a tiny gap in middle of the bodies, you will get the same result. It is, as I said before, a numerical inaccuracy. In PhysX, "Exactly Equal" does NOT mean spring apart. If you take boxes with a bigger contact surface, they will be stacked even if you push them *together* by 0.01 units. I'm not sure whether you know *how* contact separation works in a physics engine. They won't "pop apart" when placed together (or vertex snapped). Collisions (in discrete collision detection) are only reported *after* the objects have penetrated.

Comment: Objects aren't reported as colliding when there's a penetration of 0 between them, a collision is reported when penetration *>* 0. This happens when the bottom most body is pushed into the plane and subsequently the upper bodies are pushed into the bodies directly below them due to gravity. They will only "pop apart" after the second frame, and when they do, the magnitude of this "popping apart" force (or positional correction, it's technical term) is a factor (usually < 1) of the penetration. This makes it really small.

Comment: The stack topples because of the small numerical inaccuracies (there's *loads* of multiplication to do before the linear and angular positions are integrated). Again, increasing the solver count can make the simulation more stable, but in this case the contact surface area is too small.

Comment: @Domi vertex snapping is not necessarily accurate, especially when dealing with colliders because the collider may not necessarily conform to the mesh. If your bodies have simple, easy to remember dimensions (like integers and simple fractions), you should enter multiples of those values in the position field manually. You can also try surface snapping which works with colliders, not meshes, but you might still get some small errors because of numerical inaccuracies :)

Comment: I double checked first thing: The positions are 100% aligned. The numerical inaccuracies would happen no matter what, if the vertices touched at an irrepresentable number.

Comment: *Removed and moved into answer at @Domi's request*

Comment: If you remove the first sentence and amend this last part, I could make this the correct answer.

Comment: @Domi did as you asked, moved the comment into the answer too.

Comment: "In PhysX, "Exactly Equal" does NOT mean spring apart"  Heh !  it will be hilarious when you ask a question about how to set two rigidbodies so they spring apart.

Comment: @JoeBlow simple. Add a fully compressed spring simulating force to the bodies with the required spring length et al.